# How can i get rid of glitch in images on hover (Css3 hover on effect)

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the url of my website: [Website](http://new.lettucebeekids.org/image-test)

As u can see that there is a main yellow image on home page. Actually there are 11 images. I show them on mouse hovers. On hovering an image the top image hides and the bottom image appears i have done this by opacity and css3 animations for smooth transition. There are few problems in them.

1) when we hover on images a glitch comes on that respective image. (The image gets a little bigger and than gets smaller. It appears mostly in chrome. Plus on very high resolutions all image alignment also gets disturb. **Glitch only comes in image 3**

**2) I want to show my page up to yellow image in all screens weather its 1280*780 or 2280*1600 etc.**

Answer (score 4):

The "glitch" is because your imgs do not have exactly the same margins after applying CSS. There are 5 main parts to your yellow `part1`. You defined each to be `width:20%`, which is ultimately a fluid size according to the width of window, but you added an absolute margin of 2px / 3px to the top of some images, which is independent of your window size.

You should not do this as `20%` may evaluate to different pixel values - it will be 200px in a window of width 1000px, it will be 204px in a window of width 1024px. Consequently, your img heights will also vary at different window sizes. Your top margin of 2px / 3px would only work at a very specific window width, and fail to work for the majority of other resolutions. Remember, everything ultimately renders as `px`.

Looking through your source,  you also have quite a few other problems in the HTML and CSS.

1) You are using `<img>` tags for your pictures. Your `#bottom` images are nested inside `<p>` and styled to be `width: 20%` of the `<p>`, your `#top` images are styled to be `100%` of its parent, `copy1 - copy5`. Because they depend on different parents, it's tedious and tiring to trace the positions, margins, paddings of each parent and each image. Try to be consistent and make it more predictable when you want things to be overlaid exactly.

2) It is not legal to have multiple tags with same `id`, e.g. `#bottom`.

What you could / should do:

1. Redo the images (Photoshop or otherwise), to make sure they line up exactly without the need for CSS margins.
2. **After you have done 1**, redo your HTML and CSS to make it better/legal. I'd also encourage you to use `inline-block` rather than floats. A sample here (I have kept the class names as close to yours as possible, and retained use of `<img>` for this effect):

```css
.parts1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
 }

.copy {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
 }
.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
 }
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
 }
.copy:hover > .top {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parts1">
    <div class="copy" id="copy1">
        <img class="bottom" alt="Bottom1" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/plain1.png" />
        <img class="top" alt="Top1" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U2.png" />
    </div><div class="copy" id="copy2">
         <img class="bottom" alt="Bottom2" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U4.png" />
        <img class="top" alt="Top2" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U3.png" />
    </div><div class="copy" id="copy3">
         <img class="bottom" alt="Bottom3" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U5.png" />
        <img class="top" alt="Top3" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U6.png" />
    </div><div class="copy" id="copy4">
         <img class="bottom" alt="Bottom4" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U7.png" />
        <img class="top" alt="Top4" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U8.png" />
    </div><div class="copy" id="copy5">
         <img class="bottom" alt="Bottom5" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U9.png" />
        <img class="top" alt="Top5" src="http://new.lettucebeekids.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/U10.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have done this correctly, the actual window size does not really matter. It will scale to all sizes.

Comment: If i do not add margins the alignment gets disturbed actually i did photoshop for 2-3 times still they get a litle up and down. the <p> tags are coming by there self i dont now why.

Comment: Did you read my answer regarding why you should not add an absolute margin (px) to a fluid-size (%) element? Ensure that your images are the same size in Photoshop, and that they line up properly. CSS can't help you if your images don't line up properly to begin with.

Comment: Yes i have read can u please elaborate this line "  you should not add an absolute margin (px) to a fluid-size (%) element? "

Comment: Added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Ok i am giving it a fresh new try what about the problem 2)?

Comment: Like I said: if you have done this correctly, the actual window size does not really matter. It will scale to all sizes.

Comment: I mean where have u defined that the height should be fix i.e. in every screen the max height should be fixed to yellow image?

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "in every screen the max height should be fixed to yellow image". In the current website, there is also no mention of max-height. In the current site, the yellow images only get hidden below a certain resolution, most probably due to CSS media-queries.

Comment: I mean that i want to show my website to parts1 div in all screens not bellow them when website loads. After scrolling we can see below?

Comment: Why are my bottom images wrapping them selves in <p> tag by there self? iam not wrapping them. how can i fix them?

Comment: i have done it almost what u said u can see the updated link in my question.. There are now no margins every thing is perfect. But there is a glitch in image 3 please review and give me ur feed back i dont understand why its coming. It is only commung in chrome in safari and firefox its perfect

Comment: It's appearing fine on my end - Chrome and Firefox. Your issue is likely related to floating point errors calculation at certain resolutions, since percentages usually result in non-whole numbers for px values. If you're okay with changing to using css background-image rather than using img tags, I believe the problem will go away.

Comment: As for "show my website to parts1 div in all screens not bellow them when website loads", I'm guessing you mean you want the yellow images to always show up at the bottom of the screen. This requires some knowledge of the dimensions of the elements preceding it. Once you know the amount of space required to make it appear at the bottom, use padding-top/margin-top to place it there, e.g. padding-top: calc(100% - 450px) if the space taken up by the elements above (including margins/paddings) is 450px.

Comment: And just by the way, you have repeated class attributes for your images. Do yourself a favour and do a quick check of your own HTML validity. In Firefox, right click and View Page Source. All the red bold text are illegal.

Comment: The background image property does not work on some browsers when i will change them on hover. P.S. Onlt the third image is doing glitching. but if i remove width;20% from cc1 divs the glitch dispperas but there comes a space after image5 :( URL:http://new.lettucebeekids.org/image-test/

Comment: I dont know why its coming. Removing width:20%; from cc1 div makes it perfect but then a space comes on right side

Comment: here is the fiddle please review. hover second and fourth image and u will see glitch and gap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80123/discussion-between-light-and-ammar-ul-hassan).